# How to Integrate krpano to show panoramic images in flutter App

Tags: flutter, panoramas, krpano

I want to show panoramic images in flutter app.I found krpano is solution for that but i don't know how to integrate krpano in flutter app.Can you please help me out.
(i want to view this type of image- http://www.bigpixel.cn/t/5834170785f26b37002af470)